# Pass an initialized Rust struct to C and call a rust function from C with the struct as input

Tags: c, rust

I have built a library in Rust and my goal is to run it parallel with a Sat Solver (built in C) and make these two exchange information. The database (where information is received, stored and sent) is in Rust.
My problem is that I need to pass the Receiver from crossbeam channel from Rust to C and from the C program call the function receive (which takes as input the Receiver struct). The function receive is then executed in my Rust code.

I have programmed the structs and function in Rust:

```
use crossbeam_channel::Receiver;

use std::boxed::Box;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct CReceiver(Receiver<Vec<i32>>);

impl CReceiver {
    fn new(receiver: Receiver<Vec<i32>>) -> CReceiver {
        CReceiver(receiver)
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn data_new(creceiver: CReceiver) -> *mut CReceiver {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(creceiver))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn data_free(ptr: *mut CReceiver) {
    if ptr.is_null() {
        return;
    }
    unsafe {
        Box::from_raw(ptr);
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn receive(ptr: *mut CReceiver) -> Vec<i32> {
    unsafe {
        let creceiver = Box::from_raw(ptr);
        match creceiver.0.try_recv() {
            Ok(received) => received,
            Err(_) => Vec::new() // glucose can handle empty clauses
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to wrap the Receiver in a CReceiver struct to be able to pass it over to C. When I try to generate the header with cbindgen I get:

WARN: Cannot find a mangling for generic path GenericPath { path: Path { name: "Receiver" }, export_name: "Receiver", generics: [Type(Path(GenericPath { path: Path { name: "Vec" }, export_name: "Vec", generics: [Type(Primitive(Integer { zeroable: true, signed: true, kind: B32 }))], ctype: None }))], ctype: None }. This usually means that a type referenced by this generic was incompatible or not found.
WARN: Can't find Vec. This usually means that this type was incompatible or not found.
WARN: Can't find Receiver. This usually means that this type was incompatible or not found.

IMPORTANT: I need to initialise the receiver in Rust and then pass it to C as the whole channel (together with the sender) is initialised and needed.

Comment: Read your error message again. Why do you expect you can just pass a `Vec` to c-land without some change? Same for `Receiver`.

Comment: Exactly my problem. What change? For the vec I wrote a c class. But what do I do for Receiver?

Comment: Deconstruct it into things that C has. Pointers (to other C types), primitives and `#[repr(C)]` structs or unions that contain the former.